# Staircase table with TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, macros

[image: staircase table]

I would like to make a table with the following staircase pattern (preferably with TiKz). In addition for each of the cells there should be a mini-box. The minibox has further data such as a pH level while the main box has a solubility (s) or in soluable.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried so far (minimal, compilable code example; MWE).

Answer (score 5):

These are both fun exercises in using `\foreach`. The macros `\LabGrid` and `\ChemGrid`, defined below, both accept a variable number of rows/columns and `\LabGrid` has an optional argument for the colour. The MWE below produces:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%usage: \LabGrid[colour]{CAPITAL letter for last row/column}
\newcommand\LabGrid[2][purple]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
        \foreach \row [count=\r,remember=\r] in {A,...,#2} {
           \draw[fill=#1!10!white](0,-\r) rectangle ++(2,1);
           \node at (1,0.5-\r){$\row$};
           \foreach \c in {1,...,\r} {
              \draw[thick](2*\c,-\r) rectangle ++(2,1);
           }
        }
        \draw[fill=#1!10!white](0,-1-\r) rectangle ++(2,1);
        \foreach \row [count=\c] in {A,...,#2} {
            \draw[fill=#1!10!white](2*\c,-1-\r) rectangle ++(2,1);
            \node at (2*\c+1,-0.5-\r) {\row};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% usage: \ChemGrid{comma separated list of chemicals}
\newcommand\ChemGrid[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.8,
      header/.style={rectangle,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm}]
     \foreach \row [count=\r, remember=\r] in {#1} {
       \node[header] at (1.5,0.2-2*\r){\row};
       \draw(1,-2*\r)rectangle++(1,2);
       \foreach \chem [count=\c] in {#1} {
          \draw[thick](2*\c,-2*\r)--++(2,0)--++(0,2);
          \draw(2*\c+1,2-2*\r)--++(0,-1)--++(1,0);
       }
     }
     \foreach \row [count=\c, remember=\c] in {#1} {
       \node[header] at (2*\c+1,-0.3-2*\r) {\row};
       \draw(2*\c,-0.5-2*\r)--++(0,0.5);
     }
     \draw(2*\c+2,-0.5-2*\r)--++(0,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \LabGrid{C}\bigskip

  \LabGrid[green]{E}\bigskip

  \ChemGrid{NH$_4$O$_2$, BACl$_2$, CuSo$_4$}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

I realised that the nodes did not scale with `xscale` and `yscale`. I have fixed this.

As shown, the easiest way to fine-tune the sizes of the boxes is by setting `xscale` and `yscale` in the `tikzpicture` environment.