# Trouble drawing a staircase table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx, mathdesign

I know there are multiple posts on the forum related to staircase tables. Altought, I couldn't find one that fits my idea, mainly because the headers of each row / column are too small for what I want.

My desired output is exactly the picture below, but without the vertical lines that aren't being used, i.e., to only have the saircase design (as shown in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396473/staircase-table-with-tikz)).

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the `w` column type for columns 2 thru n; that way, a constant column width is assured -- which, I believe, is helpful when trying to create the "look" of a staircase. :-) The width I chose (9mm) is admittedly somewhat arbitrary and will depend on the document's font and font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newcommand{\blankcols}[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{}}
\let\veps\varepsilon

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default: 5pt
$\begin{array}{@{} r | *{8}{w{c}{9mm}|}}
\cline{1-2}
1     & \veps & \blankcols{7} \\ 
\cline{1-3}
2     & \veps & 01 & \blankcols{6} \\
\cline{1-4}
0,3   &   & \veps & \veps & \blankcols{5} \\
\cline{1-5}
0,4   & 0 & \veps & \veps & 0 & \blankcols{4} \\
\cline{1-6}
0,1,5 & 1 & \veps & \veps & 1 & 0 & \blankcols{3} \\
\cline{1-7}
1,2   & \veps & & 01 & \veps & \veps & \veps & \blankcols{2} \\
\cline{1-8} 
0,3,4 & 0 & \veps & \veps & 0 & & 0 & \veps & \blankcols{1}\\
\hline
0     & \veps & 1 & 1 & \veps & \veps & \veps & 01 & \veps \\
\hline
 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0,3 & 0,4 & 0,1,5 & 1,2 & 0,3,4 \\
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment and request: I gather that you don't want the vertical lines to extend below the final row, i.e., that the asterisks should "stand proud" of the lines. This may be done with a combination of `\underset`, `\smash[b]`, and `\vphantom` -- all combined into the macro `\astunderset` for the user's convenience. Likewise, for the asterisks on the far left of the table, I gather that they should stand proud of the (horizontal) lines; I suggest achieving this via `\mathllap` ("math left overlap"), a macro provided by the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newcommand{\blankcols}[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{}}
\let\veps\varepsilon

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\astunderset[1]{\smash[b]{\underset{\textstyle*}{#1\vphantom{,}}}}

\begin{document}
\[ % start display math mode
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{@{} r | *{8}{w{c}{9mm}|}}
\cline{1-2}
1        & \veps & \blankcols{7} \\ 
\cline{1-3}
2        & \veps & 01 & \blankcols{6} \\
\cline{1-4}
\mathllap{*\,}0,3   &   & \veps & \veps & \blankcols{5} \\
\cline{1-5}
\mathllap{*\,}0,4   & 0 & \veps & \veps & 0 & \blankcols{4} \\
\cline{1-6}
\mathllap{*\,}0,1,5 & 1 & \veps & \veps & 1 & 0 & \blankcols{3} \\
\cline{1-7}
1,2      & \veps & & 01 & \veps & \veps & \veps & \blankcols{2} \\
\cline{1-8} 
\mathllap{*\,}0,3,4 & 0 & \veps & \veps & 0 & & 0 & \veps & \blankcols{1}\\
\hline
0 & \veps & 1 & 1 & \veps & \veps & \veps & 01 & \veps \\
\hline
 & \astunderset{0} & 1 & 2 & \astunderset{0,3} & \astunderset{0,4} & \astunderset{0,1,5} & 1,2 & \astunderset{0,3,4} \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I loved it! It is almost perfect... There is only one thig missing: I also want the $\ast$ that are in the original photo. I was able to add them on the left side headers but I am having some trouble doing the same for the low end headers (column headers) any idea how to do so?

Comment: @roro - Please see the addendum I posted just now.

Comment: It is still not exactly ... numbers `01` are not in red color :-). However,  in the first I would give OP a chance to show what (s)he try so far ... OP sketch is not clear, what (s)he is after etc. Anyway +1

Comment: @Zarko - I also have no idea how important or unimportant it may be that some, but not all, instances of `01` are colored in red...

Comment: The colors are not important, I can do that by myself. It's perfect now! Thank you so much for your help!